# Does sfGuardUser table have a primary key?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I'm new to Symfony and Doctrine and am writing a web app.  I added the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin to my project.  When I open the schema.yml file for the plugin I see this:

```
sfGuardUser:
actAs: [Timestampable]
columns:
  first_name: string(255)
  last_name: string(255)
  email_address:
    type: string(255)
    notnull: true
    unique: true
  username:
    type: string(128)
    notnull: true
    unique: true
  algorithm:
    type: string(128)
    default: sha1
    notnull: true
  salt: string(128)
  password: string(128)
  is_guest:
    type: boolean
    default: 0
  is_active:
    type: boolean
    default: 1
  is_super_admin:
    type: boolean
    default: false
  last_login:
    type: timestamp
indexes:
  is_active_idx:
    fields: [is_active]
relations:
  Groups:
    class: sfGuardGroup
    local: user_id
    foreign: group_id
    refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
    foreignAlias: Users
  Permissions:
    class: sfGuardPermission
    local: user_id
    foreign: permission_id
    refClass: sfGuardUserPermission
    foreignAlias: Users
```

Does this schema generate a table with a primary key (and if so, how do I access it)?  I've looked online and most of the pages that cover the schema for sfGuardUser display an id column that is the primary key.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's `id`, accessed as sfGuardUser u --> u.id, as in...

```
$user = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->findOneById(55);
```

or...

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('u.*')
  ->from('sfGuardUser u')
  ->where('u.id = ?', 55);
$q->execute();
```

I think somewhere in the Doctrine documentation it says that Doctrine auto-generates an "id" primary key if one isn't declared in the YAML file. It used to be declared explicity in the sfGuardPlugin schema but as of Symfony 1.4.8 (I think), it's just not written.

One thing to watch out for is that elsewhere in your schema, you need to make sure that you declare the same numeric type for the other end of the foreign key relationship or otherwise it'll throw an error. I think it's just `type: integer` that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Is it good practice to explicitly define the id column in the schema for sfGuardUser?  And if so, how would you recommend defining it?

Comment: @The Traveling Coder: I personally like to define all columns in the schema as I find it clearer and I dont like Doctrine doing things for me behind the scenes. For sfGuardUser specifically however I probably wouldn't touch it as updates to the plugin itself may overwrite the schema - as happened with that relatively recent release.

Comment: While I like Symfony and Doctrine so far, I find the automagic stuff a hindrance when it come to learning a new framework.  Can you please clarify one final detail: since you recommend leaving the sfGuardUser schema untouched, then I would need to create a Profile model and relate it to sfGuardUser if I wanted to store more user data, correct? Example: [http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-customizing-sfdoctrineguardplugin](http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-customizing-sfdoctrineguardplugin)

Comment: @The Traveling Coder: Yes, exactly, a profile table with a one-to-one relationship to sfGuardUser, which means sfGuardUser is really mainly just used for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

If no primary key is given, doctrine will create an id fieldwith type bigint and with a primary key.